# Como fazer um menu que se expande ao passar o mouse em cima com react

Tags: html5, css3, react

Preciso fazer que ao passar o mouse em cima de um elemento (p), outro elemento (div) seja mostrado com `display: block`
Código:

```js
const Tag = ()=>
{
    return (
        <>
        <div className='tag-menu'>
            <p className='tag'><span>Tags</span></p>

            //Elemento que será mostrado
            <nav id='tag-nav'>
                    <br/><a className='link-tag' href='...'>Aventura</a><br/><br/>
                    <a className='link-tag' href='...'>Fantasia</a><br/><br/>
                    <a className='link-tag' href='...'>Terror</a><br/><br/>
                    <a className='link-tag' href='...'>Romance</a><br/><br/>
                    <a className='link-tag' href='...'>Poesia</a><br/><br/>
                    <a className='link-tag' href='...'>Fic. científica</a><br/><br/>
                    <a className='link-tag' href='...'>Bibliografia</a><br/><br/>
                    <a className='link-tag' href='...'>Conto</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Você pode trabalhar com estados, onde você seta um onMouseMove no elemento e é salvo no estado um 'block', onde você pode inserir um if e else no elemento que você quer mostrar.

Porém eu acho mais simples fazer essa parte do menu via css.

Eu criei este exemplo abaixo, verifique se isso pode te ajudar:

[Código do menu CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/objective-wu-ixqw2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)